# Understanding a concurrent process

Tags: python, concurrency, python-multiprocessing

I am working on building a script which does a certain IO-bound task. I need it to attempt to download a large number of datasets, recording certain information about their size before discarding the data itself.

The problem is that the source I am getting this data from doesn't provide `content-length` headers, so it's not possible to know beforehand how large the file size is. This requires that I find a way of monitoring how long a download process takes, and have a way of killing that process and continuing onto other such processes in case it takes too long (longer than, say, 60 seconds). This is necessary in order to avoid getting "stuck" on very large datasets.

`requests` doesn't provide this feature built-in, and after spending a lot of time searching for solutions I settled on running concurrent processes with a timeout via the [`pebble`](http://pythonhosted.org/Pebble/) library. My understanding is that this is a small extension to the standard lib [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html) module which adds a few safety features, namely error handling and timeouts (which is what I want).

Based on the [Process pool](http://pythonhosted.org/Pebble/#pools) example, here is my code:

```
try:
    with ProcessPool(max_workers=4) as pool:
        iterator = pool.map(get_data, process_tuples[3:6], timeout=10)

        while True:
            try:
                rows, cols, filesize, i = next(iterator)
                datasets[i]['rows'] = rows
                datasets[i]['columns'] = cols
                datasets[i]['filesize'] = filesize
            except TimeoutError as error:
                print("Function took longer than %d seconds. Skipping responsible endpoint..." % error.args[1])
            except StopIteration:
                break
finally:
    with open("../../../data/" + FILE_SLUG + "/glossaries/geospatial.json", "w") as fp:
        json.dump(datasets, fp, indent=4)
```

But this diverges from expected behavior in two ways:

1. I had thought that `timeout=10` limited the amount of time each individual download process (done by `get_data`) would take. However, when I run this on a large file, I receive a `TimeoutError` which states that my process has taken more than 30 seconds. 30 is 3 times the length of my input; that's not what I want at all. What is going on there?
2. When the `TimeoutError` is raised, instead of discarding that run and moving onto the next one (what I want) the process jumps to the `finally` block (what I don't want). I think this is a consequence of the answer to my first question.

Comment: Set `chunksize` to 1 and you'll get the desired `timeout` of 10 seconds. The library does not support the second point of your question yet. I will soon re-factor that logic in order to support such use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in `requests` you can set **[`stream=True`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/)** and use **[`Response.iter_content()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.iter_content)** to further control the workflow.

In your case, we could keep track of time passed while downloading/iterating over the response data:

```
import time
import requests

def get_content(url, timeout):
    """
    Get response data from url before timeout
    """
    start = time.time()
    data = ''
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size = 1024): # You can set a bigger chunk_size for less iterations
        if (time.time() - start) > timeout:
            response.close()
            return {'TimedOut': True, 'data': None}
        else:
            data += chunk

    response.close()
    return {'TimedOut': False, 'data': data}
```

So basically you set a `timeout` value, and if the data is too big or the network is too slow, once it spends more than `timeout` a result will get returned and those incomplete data will be garbage collected.

Next since it's IO-bound task, we could either use `threading` or `multiprocessing` to finish the job， here's an example using `threading`

```
import threading, Queue

def worker(queue):
    while not queue.empty():
        url = queue.get()

        result = get_content(url, 60)

        # Do other stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    limit = 10 # number of threads to use
    thread_pool = [None] * limit
    queue = Queue.Queue()
    urls = ['xxxx', 'xxxxx']

    for url in urls:
        queue.put(url)

    for thread in thread_pool:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(queue, ))
        thread.start()
```